# "dependencies references nonexistent parent node" error after 'pinax.notifications' added in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

After

```
pip install pinax-notifications
```

and 'pinax.notifications' added in INSTALLED_APPS
the following error showing up.

Using python 2.7.9, django 1.7.0.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\githome\eventmatch\wsgi\myproject\manage.py", line 11, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 57, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 48,
in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 241, in build_graph
    self.graph.add_dependency(migration, key, parent)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 42, in add_dependency
    raise KeyError("Migration %s dependencies references nonexistent parent node %r" % (migration, parent))
KeyError: u"Migration notifications.0001_initial dependencies references nonexistent parent node (u'contenttypes', u'0002_remove_content_type_name')"
```

Comment: hey mate, did you get to solve this?? i am having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a broken on this pinax-notifications version. The `WORKAROUND` i found was to downgrade to `pinax-notifications==2.0.1`. Now migrations seem to be working fine

refs: https://github.com/pinax/pinax-notifications/issues/47

Comment: Thanks @phychok7 ! 
I tried and found the same `downgrade to pinax-notifications==2.0.1` `WORKAROUND`, but forgot to come back to update my question.